# Cloud9/AWS SAM Environment Variables not consumed by Lambda/NodeJS Debugger

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-sam, aws-cloud9

I have a SAM deployment with a SNS Topic and a Lambda/API Gateway. The Lambda is a NodeJS Lambda that is looking for an environment variable `sns_create_collection_topic`. This is defined in my SAM template as such:

```
Resources:
  CollectionApiPostFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: 'http-post/src/'
      Environment:
        Variables:
          deployed_environment: !Ref TargetEnvironment
          sns_create_collection_topic: !Ref CollectionCreatedTopic
  CollectionCreatedTopic:
    Type: AWS::SNS::Topic
    Properties:
      DisplayName: test-topic
      TopicName: test-topic
```

When I run the Lambda in Cloud9 and access that environment variable the value is `CollectionCreatedTopic`, the explicit resource name in the template and not the ARN. The code in NodeJS to read the env var is:

```
    constructor() {
        this.aws_region = process.env.AWS_REGION;

        this.messageBus = {
            topic: process.env.sns_create_collection_topic,
        };

        console.info(this.messageBus);
    }
```

When I run `sam deploy` and *execute* the Lambda in AWS I see the ARN of the SNS Topic deployed with the template get logged, so this seems to work as intended. However when I debug it within Cloud9 using the Lambda debugger I don't see the environment variable being set to the ARN of the SNS Topic deployed.

To work around this I exported an environment variable in my *.bash_profile* on the Cloud9 EC2 with the ARN as the value.

```
sns_create_collection_topic=arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:0000000:test-sns
export sns_create_collection_topic
```

I can run `printenv` and see the environment variable correctly. I can also run `sam local start-api` and *curl* my API calls locally in Cloud9, seeing the SNS Topic ARN from my EC2 environment variable being used correctly. I'm not sure why when I run the Lambda (local) debug session within Cloud9 it is not picking up either the ARN from the SAM deployment or more strangely the environment variable on the EC2.

Am I doing something wrong or is this something not explicitly supported by Cloud9 and Lambda debugging? This doesn't appear to be an issue with SAM as it provides me all of the Cloud9 EC2 env vars when I run the Lambda with the SAM CLI via `sam local invoke` or via `sam local start-api`.

Answer (score 0):

sam local can have the input of an file to set env vars for the container.  It's format is:

`{ "LogicalFucntionName": { "env-var1': "env-var1-setting", "env-var2": "env-var2-setting" }`

I typically name my file envvars.json.   When you start sam local, use the -n switch like:

`sam local invoke LogicalFunctionName -n ./envvars.json`